# How to assign your color scale on raw data in heatmap.2()

Tags: r, plot

I have data that looks like this:

```
                         Name    h1    h2    h3    h4    h5
1            1420468_at_Asb17 0.000 2.328 0.000 0.000 0.000
2    1430261_at_1700024J04Rik 1.236 2.050 0.000 0.000 0.000
3           1431788_at_Fabp12 0.000 2.150 0.000 0.000 0.587
4    1433187_at_B230112I24Rik 0.000 2.240 1.343 0.000 1.383
5        1434430_s_at_Adora2b 0.000 2.006 1.459 0.000 1.272
6           1435217_at_Gm7969 0.727 2.350 1.494 0.976 0.000
7          1436717_x_at_Hbb-y 0.000 2.712 0.000 0.000 0.000
8            1440859_at_Akap6 0.000 2.053 0.000 0.000 1.840
9              1442625_at_--- 0.000 2.064 1.173 0.000 1.035
10           1443715_at_Rbm24 0.969 2.219 0.000 0.000 0.000
11             1445520_at_--- 0.000 2.497 0.000 0.000 0.000
12          1446035_at_Gm7173 0.000 3.869 0.000 0.000 0.000
13   1446597_at_6820445E23Rik 1.000 2.000 0.000 0.000 0.000
14          1448925_at_Twist2 0.000 2.089 0.938 0.000 0.000
15        1449711_at_Atp6v1e1 0.605 2.363 2.350 1.094 0.976
16          1455931_at_Chrna3 0.000 2.354 0.000 0.000 0.000
17 1457647_x_at_1600023N17Rik 0.000 2.734 0.000 0.000 1.812
18             1458975_at_--- 0.000 2.079 0.000 0.000 0.000
19             1459862_at_--- 0.727 2.606 0.000 0.000 1.151
```

Note in this data (and the actual one) there is no negative values and the positive values
can be as large as 100 or so.

What I want to do is to plot heat map with my own assigned color scale and scheme:

1. When the value is 0 set it into white.
2. When the value is == 1 set it into black.
3. When the value is > 1 set it into shade of reds.
4. When the value is < 1 and > 0 set it into shade of greens.

also without using any data scaling or built-in z-score transformation.
How can I achieve that?

My current code is this:

```
library(gplots)

# Read data
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1501148/plain/",sep="\t",header=T);
rownames(dat) <- dat$Name
dat <- dat[,!names(dat) %in% c("Name")]

# Clustering and distance measure functions
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="maximum")

#  Define colours
hmcols <- rev(redgreen(2750));

# Plot 
pdf("~/Desktop/tmp.pdf",height=10)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat),Colv=FALSE,dendrogram="row",scale="row",col=hmcols,trace="none", margin=c(5,10), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc,lwid=c(1.5,2.0),keysize=1);
dev.off()
```

Which produces the following plot, where it uses the default z-score row scaling.

[image]

Comment: Please clean up the question and remove unneeded parts, it's hard to understand it now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key here is understanding that `heatmap.2` uses the `col` argument in combination with the `breaks` argument.

Take a look at the code and figure below to see what I mean.

```
library(gplots)
set.seed(100)
dat = matrix( rexp(25,1/2), ncol=5 )
breaks = 0:5
col = c("green","blue","red","yellow","brown")
heatmap.2( dat, breaks=breaks, col=col )
```

[image]

As you can see, there must be `n-1` colors for `n` breaks. For your particular question, the problem is to map the correct colors to the breaks. I'm using the `scale="none"` option as @josilber pointed out.

```
breaks = seq(0,max(dat),length.out=1000)
gradient1 = colorpanel( sum( breaks[-1]<=1 ), "white", "green", "black" )
gradient2 = colorpanel( sum( breaks[-1]>1 ), "black", "red" )
hm.colors = c(gradient1,gradient2)

heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat),scale="none",breaks=breaks,col=hm.colors,
          Colv=FALSE,dendrogram="row",trace="none", 
          margin=c(5,10), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc,lwid=c(1.5,2.0))
```

[image]

Another alternative would be to have two gradients: green->black and black->red. Then, you could manually set the zero values to white by making them `NA` and setting `na.color="white"`.

```
breaks = seq(0,max(dat),length.out=1000)
gradient1 = colorpanel( sum( breaks[-1]<=1 ), "green", "black" )
gradient2 = colorpanel( sum( breaks[-1]>1 ), "black", "red" )
hm.colors = c(gradient1,gradient2)

dat[dat==0] = NA
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat),scale="none",breaks=breaks,col=hm.colors,na.color="white",
          Colv=FALSE,dendrogram="row",trace="none", 
          margin=c(5,10), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc,lwid=c(1.5,2.0))
```

And finally, you could just manually edit the gradient for the zero values.

```
breaks = seq(0,max(dat),length.out=1000)
gradient1 = colorpanel( sum( breaks[-1]<=1 ), "green", "black" )
gradient2 = colorpanel( sum( breaks[-1]>1 ), "black", "red" )
hm.colors = c(gradient1,gradient2)
hm.colors[1] = col2hex("white")

heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat),scale="none",breaks=breaks,col=hm.colors,na.color="white",
          Colv=FALSE,dendrogram="row",trace="none", 
          margin=c(5,10), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc,lwid=c(1.5,2.0))
```

[image]

*Log fold changes*

On another note, it appears that you might be looking at fold changes or some type of ratio. It is fairly common to plot the log fold changes when making a heat map. I "greyed" out the zero values.

```
dat[dat==0] = NA
heatmap.2( as.matrix(log2(dat)), col=greenred(100), 
           scale="none", na.color="grey",symbreaks=TRUE,
           Colv=FALSE,dendrogram="row",trace="none", 
           margin=c(5,10), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc,lwid=c(1.5,2.0))
```

[image]

*For an explanation of @josilber's nice solution:*

This code `hmcols <- c(colfunc1(200), colfunc2(200*(max(dat) - 1)))` makes
a character vector of length 774 (seen by `length(hmcols)`). Thus, this means that there should be 775 breaks defined. The `heatmap.2` function by default makes `n+1` breaks where `n` is the length of the vector used in the `col` argument. So the *number* of breaks and colors is worked out, but how does `hmcols <- c(colfunc1(200), colfunc2(200*(max(dat) - 1)))` map the colors to the breaks correctly? The trick is in clever way that the `hmcols` vector was created. The number of colors in the first gradient is 200. Since `breaks` was not explicitly defined, we know that the breaks will be evenly spaced. Since the first gradient goes from 0 to 1 and there are 200 breaks, the width of each break should be 0.005 (or 1/200). Since the second gradient goes from 1 to 3.869 (`max(dat)`), there should be 2.869/0.005=573.8 breaks (574 breaks when rounding up). Note that the `200*(max(dat) - 1))` does this calculation; it outputs 573.8. Thus, there are then 200+574 colors mapped to the correct breaks and everything works!

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two things here. The first is how to get rid of the z-scores. This can be done with the `scale="none"` parameter to `heatmap.2`.

The other question surrounds your desired gradient. I relied on `colorRampPalette` for this part. Below, I construct a gradient that goes white -> green -> black for values 0 through 1 and then goes black -> red for values 1 -> `max(dat)`.

```
library(gplots)

# Read data
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1501148/plain/",sep="\t",header=T);
rownames(dat) <- dat$Name
dat <- dat[,!names(dat) %in% c("Name")]

# Clustering and distance measure functions
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="maximum")

#  Define colours
colfunc1 <- colorRampPalette(c("white", "green", "black"))
colfunc2 <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "red"))
hmcols <- c(colfunc1(200), colfunc2(200*(max(dat) - 1)))

# Plot 
pdf("~/Desktop/tmp.pdf",height=10)
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat),Colv=FALSE,dendrogram="row",scale="none",col=hmcols,trace="none", margin=c(5,10), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc,lwid=c(1.5,2.0),keysize=1);
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The main theme here is to define breaks and specific colors for each break. This can be achieved by using heatmap.2 function.

```
library(gplots)
library(RColorBrewer)

#Table formatting 
rownames(df)<-df[,1] #setting row names
df<-as.matrix(df[,-1])

# Defining breaks for the color scale!
##defining color scale

myCol <- c("white",colorRampPalette(c("green","darkgreen"))(100),"black",colorRampPalette(c("red","darkred"))    (100)) 
#you can change the colors here. 
#It is important to have the total number of colors defined for all the breaks. 
#i.e if the number of breaks is 100, then there should be 99 colors defined.
#You can change the gradient of the shades by changing no of splots, 
#I have used 100 here

##defining breaks
myBreaks <- c(-1,0,seq(1e-5,1-1e-5,length=100),1,seq(1+1e-3,200,length=100)) 

#set your break start/end and the length here
# I have set it as per your requirements here. Teh shades

#Plotting heatmap 

pdf("temporal_data.pdf",width=8,height=8)
hm <- heatmap.2(df, scale="none", Colv=NA,
                col = myCol, ## using your colors
                breaks = myBreaks, ## using your breaks
                dendrogram = "row",  ## row dendograms
                , cexRow=1, cexCol=1, key=FALSE,
                margins = c(2, 12),trace="none")
legend("topleft", fill = c("white","green","black","red"),
       legend = c("0", "0.0001 to 0.999", "1",">1"),cex=1,horiz =TRUE)
dev.off()
```