# How to add an additional single column heatmap at the side of main heatmap in R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following scripts:

```
library("gplots")
mydata <- mtcars
mydata.nr <- nrow(mydata)
mydata.newval <-  data.frame(row.names=rownames(mydata),new.val=-log(runif(mydata.nr)))

# Functions
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
distfunc <- function(x) dist(x,method="euclidean")

# Set colors
hmcols <- rev(redgreen(256));

# Plot the scaled data
heatmap.2(as.matrix(mydata),dendrogram="row",scale="row",col=hmcols,trace="none", margin=c(8,9), hclust=hclustfunc,distfun=distfunc);
```

Which generate the following heatmap:
[image]

Now given a new data.frame which contain new values for each cars:

```
mydata.nr <- nrow(mydata)
mydata.newval <-  data.frame(row.names=rownames(mydata),new.val=-log(runif(mydata.nr)))
```

I want to create a single column heatmap with gradient gray positioned next to row names.
How can I achieve that in R heatmap.2?

Comment: I'd recommend the scavenging approach: look at the source code for `persp3D` or other packages which put up a colorscale by default in their graphics, and copy  the code for your own use.

Comment: If you want some more flexibility, you might try ggplot. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673162/reproducing-lattice-dendrogram-graph-with-ggplot2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want? You can use the `RowSideColors` option to add a column to the side of the heatmap.

```
new.vals = mydata.newval[,1]
mydata.newval$scaled = ( new.vals - min(new.vals) ) / 
                       ( max(new.vals) - min(new.vals) )
mydata.newval$gray = gray( mydata.newval$scaled )

heatmap.2( as.matrix(mydata), 
           dendrogram = "row", scale = "row",
           col = hmcols, trace = "none", 
           margin = c(8,9), 
           hclust = hclustfunc, distfun = distfunc,
           RowSideColors=mydata.newval$gray )
```

[image]

If you want the gray column in between the heatmap and the labels, there isn't a simple
way to do that with `heatmap.2`; I don't think it was designed for
such purposes. One way to hack it together would be to make the gray values
go from 10 to 11 (or something out of the range of the rest of the data). Then
you would change the colors mapped to the breaks (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535635/how-to-assign-your-color-scale-on-raw-data-in-heatmap-2)). However, this
would make your key look pretty funky.

```
# heatmap.2 does the clustering BEFORE the scaling. 
# Clustering after scaling might give different results
# heatmap.2 also reorders the dendrogram according to rowMeans.
# (Code copied directly from the heatmap.2 function)
x = as.matrix(mydata)
Rowv = rowMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)
hcr = hclustfunc(distfunc(x))
ddr = as.dendrogram(hcr)
ddr = reorder(ddr, Rowv) # the row dendrogram

# Scale the data as heatmap.2 does
rm = rowMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)
x = sweep(x, 1, rm)
sx =  apply(x, 1, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
x = sweep(x, 1, sx, "/")

# add the new data as a column
new.vals = mydata.newval[,1]
new.vals.scaled = ( new.vals - min(new.vals) ) / 
                  ( max(new.vals) - min(new.vals) ) # scaled from 0 to 1
x = cbind( x, gray = max(x) + new.vals.scaled + 0.1 )

# make the custom breaks and colors
edge = max(abs(x-1.1))
breaks = seq(-edge,edge+1.1,length.out=1000)
gradient1 = greenred( sum( breaks[-length(breaks)] <= edge ) )
gradient2 = colorpanel( sum( breaks[-length(breaks)] > edge ), "white", "black" )
hm.colors = c(gradient1,gradient2)

hm = heatmap.2( x, col=hm.colors, breaks=breaks,
           scale="none", 
           dendrogram="row", Rowv=ddr,
           trace="none", margins=c(8,9) )
```

[image]

Although this hack works, I would look for a more robust solution using more flexible packages that play with different viewports using the `grid` package.