# ADDING a single layer heatmap to a heatmap

Tags: r, gplots

Hi I am using R `gplots` to create a heatmap for my project.
So far I have written this code and created a heatmap successfully:

```
 library(gplots) 
    data<-read.csv("MATRIX_GAIN.txt",sep=','); 
    row.names(data) <- data$PARAMETERS
    data <- data[,2:18] 
    data_matrix<-data.matrix(data)     
    data_heatmap<-heatmap.2(t(data_matrix),
    col=redblue(256),dendrogram="none",density.info="none",scale="row",key=T,
    keysize=1.0,trace="none",cexRow=0.5, cexCol=0.6,symbreaks=T,margins=c(10, 8));
```

But now I want to add another column of data to the existing heatmap, that has a separate color scheme. Please comment.

```
PARAMETERS  List_H  List_O  List_A  List_F  List_G  List_N  List_I
A   1.2973  1.5639  0.7184  0.533   0.6628  1.2973  1.5639
B   0.1307  0.1575  0.1301  0.3805  0.6862  0.1307  0.1575
C   0.5706  0.6878  0.6306  0.3054  0.1207  0.5706  0.6878
D   1.0153  1.2239  1.0166  0.9835  0.5128  1.0153  1.2239
E   1.6615  0.7051  0.2836  -0.1766 0.706   1.6615  0.6511
F   0   0   0   0.209   0.5348  0   0
G   0.5448  0.6568  0.8642  0.6374  -0.0512 0.5448  0.6568
H   0.0658  0.0793  0.1245  0.3191  0.611   0.0658  0.0793
```

Comment: See the edit that @Csislander did; it's much easier to read with the code formatted. Check out the toolbar in the post edited for future posts.

Comment: Since you didn't include data, it's hard to see the output that you're seeing. Please following the recommendations in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to create a reproducible example.

Comment: I added a part of my data. I am not sure how to edit it. Please comment.

Comment: Thanks Mr Flick Please tell me what did you do to make the data look like this.

Comment: You just have to indent the lines by 4 spaces. If you highlight the section, and press ctrl-k it will indent it for you. So where do you want to add this column? And where is the data for this column coming from?

Comment: So I am gonna add another column showing sum of an individual parameter across all the lists. Then that column will have a separate color scheme and I can call it "SUM". I know how to add a column to a matrix but what I don't know is if I can add a separate color scheme for that column only and a legend for that as well.

Comment: I found something relative.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016022/ggplot2-heatmaps-using-different-gradients-for-categories. Thanks

Comment: @mparida Thank you for taking the time to post sample code. I was interested in finding a solution so i'm glad you found something that would work for you. If you have time, please post the solution you used as an answer to this question and accept it to close this thread.

Comment: Sure I used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778948/how-to-add-an-additional-single-column-heatmap-at-the-side-of-main-heatmap-in-r as my reference to build my solution.

Comment: Solution to my question was built on reference to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778948/how-to-add-an-additional-single-column-heatmap-at-the-side-of-main-heatmap-in-r